# JSON Parsing in java using Gson

Tags: java, json

I am attempting to run a simple HTTP server that I will send a request to with JSON string in the body and I need to extract data from it. I'm new to Java and having a difficulty doing so. Ive searched online and most of the examples dont work for me, so there must be something im doing wrong.

```
public class shareManagerServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8500), 0);
        HttpContext context = server.createContext("/shareWithUser");
        context.setHandler(shareManagerServer::handleshareWithUserRequest);
        server.start();
    }

    private static void handleshareWithUserRequest(HttpExchange exchange) throws IOException {
        if (exchange.getRequestMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("POST")) {
            Headers requestHeaders = exchange.getRequestHeaders();

            // Request body
            String body = utils.readString(exchange.getRequestBody());
    }
    }
}
```

Based on this, how would I get this to an object that I can access the JSON information with? For testing im sending this curl:

```
curl -X POST -d "{'age':26,'email':'norman@futurestud.io','isDeveloper':true,'name':'Norman'}" localhost:8500/shareWithUser
```

Edit:

From my utils:

```
public class utils {
    public static String readString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {

        ByteArrayOutputStream into = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
        for (int n; 0 < (n = inputStream.read(buf));) {
            into.write(buf, 0, n);
        }
        into.close();
        return new String(into.toByteArray(), "UTF-8"); // Or whatever encoding
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post what you tried and what problem(s) you had with it.

Comment: can you show more code what is this `utils` and also which library are you using for deserializing json?

Comment: How about `new JSONObject(body)`?

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Comment: @Deadpool added it!

Comment: my second question which json library are you using? @trever

Comment: @cricket_007 I did try that, and I get a "JSONObject() in JSONObject cannot be applied to java.lang.String"

Comment: @Deadpool I was trying with Gson and then I tried with json.simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you can create class with having all the properties

```
public class Person {

  private int age;
  private String email;
  private boolean isDeveloper;
  private String name;

  //getters and setters

  }
```

Now it is pretty string forward by using `Gson`

```
String body = utils.readString(exchange.getRequestBody());

Gson gson = new Gson();

Person person = gson.fromJson(body, Person.class);
```

Comment: ah ok I see what im going to have to do here! Thanks! Im new to Java!